# Перенос базы данных на удаленный сервер

Tags: delphi, sql-server

Есть программа на Delphi - клиентская часть + база данных на MS SQL Server 2008. На данный момент база данных расположена на локальном сервере (т.е. на моем компьютере) с Windows авторизацией. Необходимо перенести базу (бэкап базы уже сделал) на удаленный сервер (на существующих серверах уже развернуты базы с sql авторизацией, поэтому изменить там ничего не могу), но обязательно оставить windows авторизацию. Возможно ли средствами SQL Server создать новый удаленный сервер или есть какие-либо другие пути обхода данной проблемы?

Comment: Сервер должен находится на том ПК к которому вы хотите подключаться и где есть база. Зайдите в "SQL Server Management Studio" на вашем "сервере", разрешите там подключения к СУБД по сети, откройте базу, выберите логин/тип авторизации и подключайтесь. Почитайте ответы на вопросы "как настроить sql-сервер 2008" в интернете и на msdn нормально с картинками всё показано.

Comment: Windows-авторизация работает всегда, поэтому то, что на существующих серверах уже развернуты базы с sql авторизацией, никак не влияет на возможность перенести туда вашу базу. Переносите базу, переносите/создавайте Windows-логины (если их там нет) и все.

Comment: А желание/намерение "обязательно оставить Windows-авторизацию" чем вызвано?

Comment: Первое, что нужно, это найти сервер, на который вы сможете логиниться с windows авторизацией. Там базу и разворачивайте. Как правильно написали выше, если используется sql авторизация на другом сервере, это не повод развернуть базу там же.

Answer (score 1):

1) windows-авторизацию в принципе нельзя запретить на уровне сервера, отключить можно только SQL-авторизацию.

Другое дело, что если вы использовали локальные учетные записи windows, а планируете использовать, например, доменные учетные записи, или локальные учетные записи удаленного сервера, вам необходимо будет создать логины с новыми УЗ на удаленном сервере, и после привязать эти логины к существующим пользователям в базе данных.

2) Средствами SQL Server нельзя создать удаленный сервер. Удаленный сервер создается средствами установщика SQL Server - вам необходимо заново установить СУБД на удаленном сервере, после чего перенести туда базу и подключить ее.